# Geoserver Full head error

Tags: geoserver, boundless-suite

I've started getting errors from geoserver when trying to request WMS layers.
I'm running it on windows server (the OpenGeo suite version)

The errors are :

```
WARN [mortbay.log] - handle failed
java.io.IOException: FULL head
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:276)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:205)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
    at org.mortbay.thread.BoundedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(BoundedThreadPool.java:450)
```

And I'm getting pink tiles on FF or empty tiles on Chrome/IE.

The weird thing is that on geoserver itlsef I can preview the layer.

any ideas?

Comment: Does the problem persist if you restart opengeo?

Comment: Yes it does , I've read somewhere its because ExtJS state.
I've disabled it in my project , cleared the cookies and problem didn't happens again so far.
Nether the less , It will be good idea to increase the header size in opengeo , question is , how I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

headerBufferSize could be increased by adding

```
<Set name='headerBufferSize'>8192</Set>
```

into the addconnector section in Geoserver_dir/etc/jetty.xml
I am posting my exact jetty.xml snippet that needs to be changed.
Change to this:

```
<Call name="addConnector">
      <Arg>
          <New class="org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
            <Set name="port"><SystemProperty name="jetty.port" default="8080"/></Set>
            <Set name="maxIdleTime">30000</Set>
            <Set name="Acceptors">2</Set>
            <Set name="confidentialPort">8443</Set>
    <Set name='headerBufferSize'>8192</Set>
          </New>
      </Arg>
    </Call>
```

from this

```
<Call name="addConnector">
      <Arg>
          <New class="org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
            <Set name="port"><SystemProperty name="jetty.port" default="8080"/></Set>
            <Set name="maxIdleTime">30000</Set>
            <Set name="Acceptors">2</Set>
            <Set name="confidentialPort">8443</Set>

          </New>
      </Arg>
    </Call>
```

For more info read [Here](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JETTY-336)

Cheers.